# Can't install github is there an alternative?

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I'd like to download from github: https://github.com/ushahidi/SwiftRiver

I'm not familiar with Github but it's clear that I need to install it in order to download this folder/application.

I tried downloading the zip file but noticed a bunch of sub directories were missing. For example, "system" directory.

I'm using a Mac 10.6 and from research it appears that you must have 10.7 or later to install Github.

Is there an alternative? Is there some web hosted version that allows me to "clone" or run the code to create the directory? It seems so close.

Comment: Where do you get stuck when you "Can't install github"? (Yes, there might be a way to work around it, but why not just fix the original problem where the default is not working for you?

Comment: If you're just trying to download that package's source code, you can press the "Zip" button there on GitHub to download a zip file of the project. That would save you from needing to install git, if it's not something you have to work with on a regular basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're confused. Github is a website that hosts Git repositories. You can't, and don't need to, install it.

Git is a version control system. That, you can install. On the Mac, there are a number of ways to do this. Probably the easiest way is to install Xcode and the command line tools.

Comment: There's also a GitHub application; see http://mac.github.com/. But you shouldn't need it to download a project from GitHub; just `git` should be sufficient.

Comment: After you've installed Xcode, make sure you install the command line tools from within Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to install Github in order to download this project.

You need GIT from [here](http://git-scm.com/downloads).

Then you can follow the instruction from https://github.com/ushahidi/SwiftRiver

Open a terminal, create a folder, e.g. `git`, go to this folder and use:

> git clone --recursive git://github.com/ushahidi/SwiftRiver.git

This will clone the code into a newly created SwiftRiver directory. Copy this directory to your web server's document root or public_html directory.

I recommend to you to read a [great GIT documentation](http://git-scm.com/doc)